# 3 select in the same query where "where" is different date time

Tags: php, mysql

**I need to make a query with 3 Select where "where" is different date time.**
I need help with this, I did not see anything similar in other posts, thanks!

the problem is that I see only the first select "op_suma" and I do not see op_suma_a and op_suma_b. In the while I have no results.

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT *, count(*) as op_suma from galog where fecha_hora > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) 
        UNION
        SELECT *, count(*) as op_suma_a from galog where fecha_hora > (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
        UNION
        SELECT *, count(*) as op_suma_b from galog where fecha_hora > (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) group by operadora";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if (!$conn) {
    die('No pudo conectarse: ' . mysql_error());
}

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo"<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["id_red"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["operadora"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["op_suma"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["op_suma_a"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["op_suma_b"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row["fecha_hora"] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 resultados";
}
```

Comment: And?  What happens?

Comment: Please read [ask]. We can't help you if you don't tell us what the problem is.

Comment: you have errors ? show the error message .. wrong result  .. show a proper data sample you actual result and the expected  one

Comment: Don't make an answer out of an edit.  Add your 'answer' to the text of the question.

Comment: the problem is that it shows only the result of the last minute column.

Comment: When you are using a union, the column-count has to match, so op_suma_a, op_suma_b, and op_suma are all going to be treated as the same thing.  If you have to separate these values, then you'll need a join instead of a union.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, you should be using a join instead of a union (if I understand what you are trying to do correctly).  However, if you have to use a union, or if there is no column/value to use for a join, you could alter the query variable to look like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, count(*) as op_suma, null as op_suma_a, null as op_suma_b from galog where fecha_hora > (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) 
    UNION
    SELECT *, null as op_suma, count(*) as op_suma_a, null as op_suma_b from galog where fecha_hora > (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
    UNION
    SELECT *, null as op_suma, null as op_suma_a, count(*) as op_suma_b from galog where fecha_hora > (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) group by operadora";
```

Note the null values in each of the unioned-queries.  This will give you values in each column so you can get them with each alias (op_suma, op_suma_a, op_suma_b), but the others will have null values, so it will still be hard to work with.

Again, this would ideally be done with a join **OR with three separate queries**